# Magento API/Soap in subdomain Nginx

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, nginx

I have existing magento 1.9.0.1 running on Nginx.
it is possible to listen API on another subdomain?

e.g. http://api.example-e.com point to api on www.example-e.com/api/soap/?wsdl=1

I have try before using server listener, but the soap url it always point to www.example-e.com/api/soap/?wsdl=1

this is response login function

WSDL
         SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.example-e.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1' : Premature end of data in tag html line 4
         ﻿

Any suggestion?

Comment: Finally, I've decided to use lampp on my cloud. So it can invoked soap api without problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've decided to use lampp on my cloud instead of nginx. So it can invoked soap api without problem. So far I trying spliting SOAP API into subdomain, it is impossible because magento have static API that will be included url on response.